# Why .widget-area is outside of .site-content in Underscores starter theme?

Tags: theme-development, html

The Underscores starter theme offers a specific HTML structure:

```
div.site
    header#masthead.site-header

    div#content.site-content
        div#primary.content-area
            main#main.site-main
                /* Here goes either article or archive content */

    aside#secondary.widget-area
        section.widget /* Multiple widgets */

    footer#colophon.site-footer
```

The `aside#secondary.widget-area` seems to be out of place. Looks like it should be inside of `div#content.site-content`, as a sibling of `div#primary.content-area`.

Is there a specific reason why Underscores theme HTML is structured this particular way?

Comment: If you think there's something wrong or have questions, you should raise it with the authors: https://github.com/automattic/_s/issues

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `.widget-area` actually **IS** inside `.site-content`.

For anyone wondering why `.content-area` has a `<main>` child-element, rather than being the `<main>` element itself, here is the explanation:

It allows for CSS styling while preserving HTML5 semantics. Namely it allows for easier negative margin management as well as background and other styling ([full explanation here](https://github.com/Automattic/_s/issues/370)).